# How does the Swift String replaceRange method deal with empty ranges

Tags: ios, swift

Is it expected that when calling `replaceRange` on a Swift string with a range that has the same start and end index that the `replaceRange` method will insert a new character and make the string longer?

For example with this method:

```swift
func replaceCharAtPositionForWord(word:String, position: Int, char: Character) -> String {
    var newWord : String = word;
    var range : Range = Range<String.Index>(start: advance(newWord.startIndex, position),
                                           end:advance(newWord.startIndex, position+1))

    newWord.replaceRange(range, with: String(char))
    return newWord;
}
```

Calling `replaceCharAtPositionForWord("Hello", 3, Character("a"))` returns "Helao" as expected.

But if instead the `Range` above is setup as:

```swift
var range : Range = Range<String.Index>(start: advance(newWord.startIndex, position),
                                       end:advance(newWord.startIndex, position))
```

Then the code inserts a new character and expands the string result to be "Helalo"

Is this what is expected from a `Range` that has no length?

Comment: `replaceRange` doesn't require that the range you replace has the same length as your replacement. This is consistent with the array subscript, which can accept ranges and [can be used to replace ranges with sequences of a different size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW15).

Answer (score 1):

You should set start and end positions:

```
text?.replaceRange(
        (text?.startIndex.advancedBy(
            range.location // start position
            ))!..<(text?.startIndex.advancedBy(
                range.location + range.length // end position
                ))!,
        with: string)
```